# Does JS Set.has() method do shallow checks?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I have a set of objects, like

```
const s = new Set();
s.add({a: 1, b: 2});
s.add({a: 2, b: 2});
```

and I will do

```
s.has({a: 1, b: 2});
```

**Will I have a positive result? How does `Set` handle reference types? Is there a way to tell it to use custom checker/predicate?**

Comment: Did you try it yourself?

Comment: It will work the same as === operator. so no

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected that any native JavaScript API compare objects by their references and not their contents (including shallow comparison):

```
({a: 1, b: 2}) !== ({a: 1, b: 2})
```

`Set` isn't an exclusion, it [does `===` comparison for every value but `NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Value_equality) when it looks up values with `has` or stores unique values.

This could be achieved by extending `Set` and using deep comparison in `has`, etc. methods but it would be inefficient.

A more efficient way is to use `Map` instead, because entries should be stored and retrieved by normalized keys, but actual objects are supposed to be stored. This can be done by using `JSON.stringify`, but object keys should be preferable sorted as well, so third-party implementation like [`json-stable-stringify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stable-stringify) may be used.

At this point there are may be not much benefits from extending either `Set` or `Map` because most methods should be overridden:

```
class DeepSet {
  constructor (iterable = []) {
    this._map = new Map();
    for (const v of iterable) {
      this.add(v);
    }
  }

  _getNormalizedKey(v) {
    // TODO: sort keys
    return (v && typeof v === 'object') ? JSON.stringify(v) : v;
  }

  add(v) {
    this._map.set(this._getNormalizedKey(v), v);
    return this;
  }

  has(v) {
    return this._map.has(this._getNormalizedKey(v));
  }

  // etc
}
```

Notice that this set is intended only for plain objects that can be correctly serialized to JSON. There may be other ways to serialize object contents but none of them will handle all possible values correctly, e.g. symbols and class instances.

Answer (score 3):

According to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether
>   primitive values or object references.

As you are adding objects, their references will be stored internally and your check will return `false` because your are passing different object to `has` method.

Actually, your case is even covered in the [Examples section of the *has* method reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has#Examples).

Answer (score 2):

In regards to objects, Sets handle unique *references*.

`new Set([ {a: 1}, {a: 1} ])` has two items.

`var x = {a: 1}; new Set([ x, x ]);` has one item.

There is no way to have Set use a custom comparison function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare references like arrays and objects for equality. You can compare values though!!!

```
const s = new Set();
let a = {a: 1, b:2};
let b = {a: 2, b: 3};
s.add(a);
s.add(b);

s.has(a); //true
```

[MDN equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)